# Trying to learn autowire using annotations in spring , and i am having error " Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. ",spring annotation

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-annotations

**Trying to learn autowire using annotations in spring , and i am having "   Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.   " error**

I created a emp class and address class , i was trying to using @Autowired annotations for autowiring address obj into emp

Emp.java class

```
package com.collection.autowire;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Emp {

@Autowired
private Address address;

    //here getters and setters , constructors 


}
```

Address.java

```
package com.collection.autowire;

public class Address {
private String streetName;
private String city;

//here getters and setters , constructors 

 }
```

test.java

```
package com.collection.autowire;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

ClassPathXmlApplicationContext container = new 
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/collection/autowire/autoconfig.xml");

    Emp emp=container.getBean("emp1",Emp.class);

    System.out.println(emp);
}

}
```

autoconfig.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="https://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:p="https://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
https://www.springframework.org/schema/context
https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
">

<context:annotation-config/> 

<bean  class="com.collection.autowire.Address" name="address">

    <property name="streetName" value="temp" />
    <property name="city" value="Pune" />
</bean>


<bean  class="com.collection.autowire.Emp" name="emp1" />
</beans>
```

pom.xml

4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.springcore</groupId>
<artifactId>springcore</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>springcore</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.20</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.20</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

AND THE ERROR LOG

```
   Exception in thread "main" 
   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 11 in XML 
   document from class path resource [com/collection/autowire/autoconfig.xml] is invalid; 
   nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 4; cvc- 
   elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanD efinitionReader.java:402)
    at 
 org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:232)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:203)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:128)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.collection.autowire.Test.main(Test.java:10)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 11; columnNumber: 4; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
    at java.x

ml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2133)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:830)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:374)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:613)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3079)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:836)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:542)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:889)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:825)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:247)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:77)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:432)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:390)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: Your mapping is wrong. You map beans to `http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` however what you use for the xsd is `https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans` those need to match.

Answer (score -1):

try wrapping your beans with tag "beans" see for a referrence
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html

```
<beans>
    //first bean declaration
    <bean ...></bean>
    //another bean declaration
    <bean ...></bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: He already does that at that errors out.

Answer (score -1):

1. Make sure the **xsd** file **path** is correct
2. convert **name** to **id** in bean attribute ,Because the given **bean** is reached by the **id**

Comment: The path is correct, the mapping is wrong.

Comment: **<bean id="any id"  class="packeg.java class"></bean>** This is how the bean is defined, and it is accessed via the **id** **ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.getBean(id,classType)** see https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/xsd-configuration.html